# Minimal Linux distribution with sshd and apt

Tags: linux, debian

When I signed up for my Debian Linux VPS hosting and first logged on and invoked `ps`, there was the only user process running: `sshd`. As I can see, this was minimal Linux with only two things installed and configured: `sshd` and `apt` (plus all dependencies, of course).

I want to build (or use existing) similar Linux distro, any advice on how to build (or pick) one?

Googling "minimum linux", or "linux with sshd only" usually brings up Debian's netinstall, which is not what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voting to close this question as this belongs to superuser.com.

Comment: Gentoo or Slackware, there are plenty of good distros. Look around, anyway vote up for tommieb75.

Comment: "Lunix" distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inclined to `roll your own` , you might like using [debootstrap](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/426). You can quickly make a very very minimal (you'll even need to generate your own locales) distro using it in just a few minutes, based on any distro that uses apt.

Pair it with your kernel version of choice, and you have a very bare bones system.

I prefer using `chroot` to add what I want prior to copying it over to boot media (you'll need to do that to install ssh / etc)

Answer (score 3):

First, `ps aux` gives me a full listing of everything running on the system, including system processes. Did you mean `ps ux`?

Second, you said that `sshd` was the only user process running? What about `bash`? What about `ps`? That's a *user process*. The number of running user processes really has no reflection on how few system internals are running; that's why the call it a user process and not a system process.

Third, if `sshd` is the only *system* process running, how does did the computer start up (`init`), or deal with TTY connections (`getty` or `agetty`), or log system events (`syslogd` and `klogd`)? Truth is, there is a very specific reason for each system process and disabling or `kill`-ing them can lead to a dumb computer, or a crashed computer.

Udev is pretty much always going to show up in `ps` listings on any 2.6.xx system. With the move from Kernel 2.4 to 2.6, the udev subsystem is standard unless you compile your own kernel. If you compile udev support out, then you'll have to rely on an unchecked `/dev` structure, which may cause problems.

If you're really looking to use your own minimalistic Linux install, use [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) or [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) and only install what you want.

Comment: Correct remark about `bash` and `ps`. I did `ps aux` and in addition to these two, sshd was the only process whose name wasn't in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite a big fan of Arch Linux for this minimalist kind of installation.  I recently set up a VM whose sole purpose was to act as an SFTP repository, separated from my main server.  It has a serial and a tty1 `agetty` running, `syslog-ng`, `udev` and `sshd`.

The nice thing about Arch for this is that it's quite easy to set it up so that very little starts up by default, just edit `rc.conf` and set these to run like so:

`DAEMONS=(syslog-ng network sshd)`

With a base Arch installation, I only actually removed the entry to mount network filesystems, and added sshd.

The downside to Arch is that the development libraries are installed with each package, so it's not as minimalist on disk space as an extremely pared down Debian can be.  Also, it uses `pacman` instead of `apt` so it doesn't really fulfill the stringent requirements of your question, but I do personally feel it's a viable alternative.

Obligatory link to get started, if you're interested: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide

Answer (score 0):

[Damn small linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/)

Comment: Have you read the question? Does it sound like I need XMMS in the distro?

Answer (score 0):

If you are into building it yourself try [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) then.
Or get the smallest distro you can find and install what you need :)

P.S. This should be on SU.

Answer (score 0):

***[Slax](http://www.slax.org/build.php)*** is a modular Linux - you can basically pick what you want on their website wizard, and download an image - how neat is that? :D

(Whilst the recommended modules seem to be X-based, presumably you can make a Slax image without X)

Answer (score 0):

[Trisquel](http://trisquel.info)

- has `apt-get`
- can use LXDE

"Trisquel Mini" download is 456 MB